# Error thrown when opening e-mails using outlook api

Tags: c#, outlook, office-interop, outlook-2007

**Question:** I get the following error message when opening what appear to be valid .MSG files using Outlook API to open emails:

> Unable to cast COM object of type
>   'System.__ComObject' to interface type
>   'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem'.
>   This operation failed because the
>   QueryInterface call on the COM
>   component for the interface with IID
>   '{00063034-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}'
>   failed due to the following error: No
>   such interface supported (Exception
>   from HRESULT: 0x80004002
>   (E_NOINTERFACE)).

The MSG files open fine in outlook and I'm assured that the forms are standard outlook mail forms.

What is the most likely cause of this error?

**Background:** One of my colleagues has exported a large number of mailboxes from exchange as PSTs and then run a tool against the PST files to produce a file-structure resembling the original mailbox filled with .MSG files. For example:

\USERNAME
\USERNAME\INBOX
\USERNAME\SENT
\USERNAME\DRAFTS
\USERNAME\DELETED

I then scan these folders for .MSG files and attempt to open them using Outlook API.

```
Outlook.Application app = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();

Outlook.NameSpace ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI");

Outlook.MailItem item = (Outlook.MailItem)ns.OpenSharedItem(EmailPath);

Subject = item.Subject;
```

Comment: can we also see the code that has generated this exception?

Comment: Try casting to Outlook.NoteItem instead. Does it help?

Comment: @Davide: the code at the end of the question generated the exception

Comment: @Daniel: Same problem with NoteItem

Comment: According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff869733.aspx), the return type of this method depends on the type inside the msg file...

Comment: @Daniel: is there a way to determine the type within the msg file?

Comment: I don't know, sorry. I have never used this API.

Answer (score 0):

All *Item objects in OOM implement the Type property. Retrieve that property dynamically using reflection instead of casting the returned object to MailItem.

OK use the "as" operator to test for the interface you are interested in without raising an exception.