# Read Outlook mails from C#

Tags: c#, outlook-2007

The above said task seems so simple as per this stack overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2055811/get-unread-mails-from-outlook) or this MSDN [How To](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms268998%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

But I am just struck at the line `foreach (Outlook.MailItem mail in items)`, where I get an exception saying "**Unable to cast** COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.MailItem' ...".

Though there are quite a [few](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583134/error-thrown-when-opening-e-mails-using-outlook-api) posts about this exception, none could help me in getting over it.

Can someone please help me to solve this and to be able to read the emails from C#.

Thanks

Comment: You could try this: foreach (var mail in items), at least you will be able to check the item type of mail in the next line.

Comment: I tried that. It is a "System.__ComObject".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not every item in an Outlook Explorer is necessarily a `MailItem`. For example, public folders contain `PostItem`s. If I remember correctly, conflict messages and meetings request also have their own item type.

Thus, I would design the loop as follows:

```
foreach (object item in items) {
    var mail = item as MailItem;
    if (mail != null) {
        // do something useful
        ...
    } else {
        // log or show some message box, so that you can debug this case
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Agree. In debugger I am able to see the contents of the 'Item' and it happens to be the Welcome email from Gmail (first mail). Just a simple plain email. Wouldn't that be a MailItem? By your design, 'mail' is still null for this email. This is my first Outlook program hence I'm not sure of its types.

Comment: @Vishruth: Does this happen for *all* mails or are there some which are of type MailItem?

Comment: You are right. I doesn't happen for all mails. It happens only for some. Thanks for your help.